# How to fetch json data with "( )" this brackets instead of this "[ ]"?

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I created a localhost web API using NodeJS...When I tried to fetch data using JSON serialization I got a JSON response like this

```
(
        {
        "__v" = 0;
        "_id" = 5b37dbd9a8da053fc8cfec9d;
        address = karaikal;
        dob = 27091995;
        gender = male;
        name = "Dhanush kumar";
        password = hithere;
    }
)
```

So because of this brackets "( )" I cant able to fetch name from those JSON outputs. Please help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/api/products")

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error")
                }else{
                    if let content = data
                    {
                        do{
                          let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                            print(myJson)
                            if let name = myJson["name"] as? NSArray
                            {
                                print(name)
                            }

                        }catch{
                            print("U GOT AN ERROR")
                        }
                    }
                }
            };task.resume()



        }




    }
```

Comment: Your JSON is an Array at top level. So you can't do `myJSON["someKeyLikeName"]`, that's not a Dictionary. And clearly: `if let name = myJson["name"] as? NSArray`, even if `myJSON["name"]` worked, how is it supposed to be an Array?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with your solution ...it shows nil :(

Comment: Where does it show nil?

Comment: print(myJson["name"]) when i try to do like this...it shows nil

Comment: The *JSON response* is not JSON, it's the output of a Swift array. And the result of `jsonObject(with` is **never** `AnyObject` in Swift 3+. And `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift. And rather than quite meaningless `"U GOT AN ERROR"` print the actual `error` instance.